# How can I cast '*anyopaque' to '[]const u8'?

Tags: sdl, zig

I'm interacting with the [SDL zig bindings](https://github.com/MasterQ32/SDL.zig)

- I have a `Surface`, which contains a pointer to some pixels. In C, this is a `void*`, in zig it is an `*anyopaque`
- I want to pass this pointer-to-pixels to the `UpdateTexture` function, which in C accepts a `void*` and in zig accepts a `[]const u8`

`@ptrCast` gives me "illegal pointer cast to slice", so what *is* the correct way to treat an opaque pointer as a slice?

Comment: use `std.mem.asBytes()`

Answer (score 1):

Cast `*anyopaque` to a many-item pointer first, then make it into a slice. E.g.

```
var anyopaque_pointer: *anyopaque = ...
var item_count: usize = ...

var result: []const u8 = @as([*]u8, @ptrCast(anyopaque_pointer))[0..item_count];
```